# Using np.nan in a JSON file and calling it in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a code where I am mapping a part of it from a JSON file. Below is the JSON code snippet and I have a condition where, if High is present, then max operation would be applied and if Low then min respectively.

And if any `np.nan` is present in the python dataframe, then 'max' has to be called. How shall I call this np.nan in the json? It doesn't accept without the quotes and it doesn't work if i give the quotes.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
  'Mode' : {'High':"max",
            'Low':'min',
            np.nan:'max'}
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how you read and use the data in python code? A [mre] would be perfect.

Comment: "Below is the JSON code snippet" That is not JSON, that is a Python `dict`. Python `dict` is not JSON, and can only in certain cases be serialised as JSON. All JSON keys must be strings, no exceptions.

Comment: JSON is somewhat limited in the data types it can use. It definitely doesn't know about `np.nan`. You'll either need to use a different serialization method or include it in the JSON as a string and convert it within your code.

Comment: @Amadan Yes. You are right. This is a Python dict. So I wanted to use it a config json file, instead of going and modifying the code everytime.

Comment: @glibdud Yes. You are right. Created a string in JSON and then calling it in my code.

Comment: @bracco23 Please find the approach I followed in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do that, so I assigned a string in json for nan like below and used that in my code.

```
with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
   config= json.load(f)

mode= config['Mode']
mode[np.nan]=mode['not_a_number']
```

While my config file for nan is modified to this:

```
"not_a_number":"max"
```

And then I use this in my Python code as below:

```
df['Mode'] = df.sample.map(mode)
```